# Set Identity in existing column of table in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am facing one critical issue in **SQL Azure** database, i have created this database from local sql server database and in that one table i have set isidentity property.

Today i have deleted that table and created it again through SQL Azure portal but i could not able to set **identity** column on that! I have tried with sql query also like below

> alter table mytablename  alter column id  identity(1,1)

gives me error like

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'identity'.

Please suggest me some technique by which i can alter this column and set isidentity property.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: should id be an int? did you try this?
alter table mytablename alter column id int identity(1,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case i have use [RazorSQL](http://www.arunrana.net/2011/11/razorsql-very-useful-client-to-manage.html) to alter this table and first dropped that table and recreate using sql query and it's worked